The meaning of "save by tower" from "A Dog of Flanders"
I found that "save" means "except for" in a dictionary.  But I don't understand why after "save" comes "by" in a sentence below.
I quoted some sentences.
Flanders is not a lovely land, and around the burgh of Rubens it is perhaps least lovely of all.
Corn and colza, pasture and plough, succeed each other on the characterless plain in wearying repetition, and save by some gaunt gray tower, with its peal of pathetic bells, or some figure coming athwart the fields, made picturesque by a gleaner's bundle or a woodman's fagot, there is no change, no variety, no beauty anywhere;
Thank you very much for your help.

It's true that save for is a common way to say except for. But it's not the only way save is used. For example Merriam-Webster gives these example sentences:

Of his earlier years little is known, save that he studied violin.
No hope save one.

Your sentence is admittedly complex. But the way I read it is to take save by itself, meaning except, and take the word by as applying to the following objects that break the monotony of the landscape.
We could get the sense of the writing by rearranging it like this:

Flanders is not a lovely land, and around the burgh of Rubens it is
perhaps least lovely of all. Corn and colza, pasture and plough,
succeed each other on the characterless plain in wearying repetition,
and there is no change, no variety, no beauty anywhere save [that created]
by some gaunt gray tower, with its peal of pathetic bells, or
some figure coming athwart the fields, made picturesque by a gleaner's
bundle or a woodman's fagot.


Maybe I could mention that 'colza' is what Brits call 'rapeseed'? Yellow flowers, always give me terrific hay-fever.

@MichaelHarvey that's new to me. Also called 'canola' across the pond.

I suffer badly from hay fever too. If I knew this I may have stayed away from the question!
